# Type of Argument dependent on another Argument

Tags: c#, .net

I doubt this is possible but what I would like to do is have an argument's type depend on the value of another argument. Because it is statically defined most of the time it should work when it can(in my case it will always be used statically).

e.g.,

suppose we had a function myFunc who's first argument was an enum of type myEnum.

```
myFunc(myEnum.SomeValue);
```

But now suppose we wanted the second argument's type to depend on the value of the first.

So

```
myFunc(myEnum.Value1, x)
myFunc(myEnum.Value2, y)
```

in this case x would have a type that is related to Value1 and y to Value2.

It should be perfectly valid for the compiler to directly determine the type of the 2nd argument if we could specify a map. We might need a new type to handle it but as long as the first argument is a compile time constant there should be no problem with it. One can use polymorphism to handle the various cases too or, in my case, using a factory.

The only type the compiler cannot deduce the type of the 2nd argument is when the first is not a compile time constant in which case a run time error can be thrown if the 2nd argument is not of the proper time.

The main point of doing this is to break a large enum into smaller ones that form a hierarchy. One could simply have a single large enum containing all the combinations but it gets out of control very quickly.

I seriously doubt C# supports such a feature but maybe there is a possible way to get it to work(using attributes or whatever)?

---

Example of behavior

```
    public enum Value1Types { Type1, Type2 }

    public enum Value2Types { TypeA, TypeB }

    public class FakeEnum
    {
        public class EnumTypes
        {
            public abstract class BaseEnum { public abstract int Value { get; } }
            public class Value1 : BaseEnum { public override int Value { get { return 1; } } }
            public class Value2 : BaseEnum { public override int Value { get { return 2; } } }
        }

        public static class EnumValues
        {
            // Singletons
            public static readonly EnumTypes.Value1 Value1 = new EnumTypes.Value1();
            public static readonly EnumTypes.Value2 Value2 = new EnumTypes.Value2();
        }

        public void AcceptValue(EnumTypes.Value1 typeController, Value1Types s) { Console.WriteLine("Value1 " + s.ToString()); }
        public void AcceptValue(EnumTypes.Value2 typeController, Value2Types s) { Console.WriteLine("Value2 " + s.ToString()); }

        public void Test()
        {
            // Notice how the same method's second arugment's type depends on the value of the first
            AcceptValue(EnumValues.Value1, Value1Types.Type1); // valid
            AcceptValue(EnumValues.Value2, Value2Types.TypeA); // valid
            //AcceptValue(EnumValues.Value1, Value2Types.TypeB); // Invalid, compile error
        }
    }
```

Comment: I believe this may be possible with [dependent typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type). However, you should really ask yourself if this (1) is the best solution in this case (taking the problems and complexity it brings into account), (2) whether C#'s typesystem should really be that sophisticated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can replace the enums with explicit types you can make something like this.
Personally I think it is to much work to get the last bit of compile time checking.

```
public class FakeEnum
{
    public class EnumTypes
    {
        public abstract class BaseEnum
        {
            public abstract int Value { get; }
        }

        public class Value1 : BaseEnum
        {
            public override int Value
            {
                get { return 1; }
            }
        }

        public class Value2 : BaseEnum
        {
            public override int Value
            {
                get { return 2; }
            }
        }
    }
    public static class EnumValues
    {
        // Singletons
        public static readonly EnumTypes.Value1 Value1 = new EnumTypes.Value1();
        public static readonly EnumTypes.Value2 Value2 = new EnumTypes.Value2();
    }

    public void AcceptValue(EnumTypes.Value1 typeController, string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Value1 " + s);
    }

    public void AcceptValue(EnumTypes.Value2 typeController, int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Value2 " + i);
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        AcceptValue(EnumValues.Value1, "with value1"); // valid
        AcceptValue(EnumValues.Value2, 1); // valid
        //AcceptValue(EnumValues.Value1, 4); // Invalid, compile error
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this does work. One just has to use overload on the enum for second argument(instead of string and int). It seems to get the exact behavior except for the FakeEnum. Much more overhead than I would like but it's nice to know that it can at least be done some way.

Comment: I agree that it is too much work and would be much easier for the compiler to do so(it would simply determine the type of the second argument using the value of the first and a lookup table). The good news is that you did find a solution that gives the correct behavior. I'm not sure how useful the code is in practice but any solution is better than none.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any language that has this feature nor why it would be useful.
If you want a function that takes different types then use overloading, i.e.

```
void myFunc(TypeX x);

void myFunc(TypeY y);
```

You could then make the decision on which to call in your code:

```
TypeX x = new TypeX();
TypeY y = new TypeY();

switch (myEnum) 
{
    case myEnumType.Value1:
        myFunc(x);
        break;
    case myEnumType.Value2:
        myFunc(y);
        break;
}
```

To try and implement this at compiler level would probably involve some nasty syntax for a marginal situation.

Comment: It should be quite easy to do this at compile time. Simply use the lookup as the type for the second argument. It should be extremely simple. If the first type is not statically passed(by which I mean it is known at compile time) then one would have to resort to a dynamic check at runtime or one could just throw an error.

Comment: I guess my difficulty with this is that I can't see an application for this construct and so I can't see the problem you are trying to solve. This just feels wrong on so many levels. Can you give some background on the problem you are trying to solve, may be there's a better approach than this.